# I need advice to structure my (vanila) Js code

Tags: javascript

I just need a bit of guidance.

I have 4 HTML pages that I want to display all with the same BG and with no scroll. So I though about positioning all of them absolute and using Js to show them as the user navigates. Right now I'm doing it in the most ridiculous way possible, which is by adding Event Listeners to my menu buttons that change the opacity to the page I want to display to 1 and all the others to 0. It is such a simple task yet my code is ginormous and super repetitive. I don't really need a detailed answer, just something for me to research, like "put this, or that in arrays", "loop trough this" and so on...

In case my question wasn't very clear, this is what I'm trying to achieve: https://sii.im/#!/. Its a super cool portfolio that I found.

Comment: If your code is working, but you want someone to review it for best practices, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be the better site for it.  Your question seems too broad for Stack Overflow as it does not include a clear way for us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have done in the past is to use javascript to load a div element with another web page. This is easily done using jQuery with the below:

```
$('#myDiv').load('home.html');
```

Then you would set up a template that contains all of your common elements as your base file, and then load the HTML of each page with simple JavaScript.

There are also many template frameworks that exist, which can add more features to using a template as a base and then loading server response data into your website. One I have used is [Jinja](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/).

This compartments your large HTML file into many smaller files, and removes duplicate code that exists in each HTML file into your template file. It also makes it much much easier to maintain your code as your template contains all base code and each individual file only contains the code you need for that portion of your site.

The JavaScript and CSS can also be moved into their own file and linked into the template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does! I asked for advice and you gave me. Thank you!

Comment: Great! (Remember to accept the answer or vote if you like it)